# Don't escape single quotes with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, system.text.json, single-quotes

I would like .net core System.Text.Json to ignore the single quote character when escaping characters for serialization but I just can't get it to work:

```
var encoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings();
encoderSettings.AllowRange(UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin);
encoderSettings.AllowCharacters('\u0027');

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions{ 
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(encoderSettings) 
};

System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { text = "abc 'zorro' 123" }, options);
```

This will result in a string:

> `{"text":"abc \u0027zorro\u0027 123"}`

When I would like it to be

> `{"text":"abc 'zorro' 123"}`

Any ideas here? Just want to not escape the single quotes. I've also tried to replace the `\u0027` with a `\'`.

If I do it like this - it works:

```
options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
};
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { text = "abc 'zorro' 123" }, options);
```

...but this will also disable escaping for all characters including `<`, `>` and `&` (excepting only characters that the JSON standard requires to be escaped), which I also don't want.

Comment: "_...but of course I can't have it like that_" But that's how it works. If you can't have it like that, then i guess you have to accept the output with the escaped single quotes. Or what _precisely_ and _exactly_ makes you not want to do it?

Comment: hmm, okey? So you think it's OK to allow all html-characters when I only need single quotes? The question is why doesn't my code work. What am I missing, or have I misunderstood the AllowCharacters feature?

Comment: Please add this to the question. The question as-is doesn't make it really clear that you only want single quotes to be not escaped, while keeping other unsafe characters escaped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior is documented in *[How to customize character encoding with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/character-encoding#block-lists)*:

> **Block lists**
>
> The preceding sections show how to specify allow lists of code points or ranges that you don't want to be escaped. However, there are global and encoder-specific block lists that can override certain code points in your allow list. ***Code points in a block list are always escaped, even if they're included in your allow list.***
>
> **Global block list**
>
> The global block list includes things like private-use characters, control characters, undefined code points, and certain Unicode categories, such as the Space_Separator category, excluding `U+0020 SPACE`. ... *<snip>*
>
> **Encoder-specific block lists**
>
> Examples of encoder-specific blocked code points include `'<'` and `'&'` for the HTML encoder, `'\'` for the [JSON encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder), and `'%'` for the URL encoder. ... *<snip>*

So, as documented, [`JavaScriptEncoder.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.create?view=net-6.0) may override your allowed characters and escape certain "blocked" characters.  While the full set of blocked characters is not documented, from the reference source, [`JavaScriptEncoder.Create(TextEncoderSettings settings)`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.10/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/JavaScriptEncoder.cs#L43) constructs an encoder that blocks "HTML sensitive" characters, which are defined in [`AllowedBmpCodePointsBitmap.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.10/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/AllowedBmpCodePointsBitmap.cs#L47) and include `'`:

> ```
> public void ForbidHtmlCharacters()
> {
>     ForbidChar('<');
>     ForbidChar('>');
>     ForbidChar('&');
>     ForbidChar('\''); // can be used to escape attributes
>     ForbidChar('\"'); // can be used to escape attributes
>     ForbidChar('+'); // technically not HTML-specific, but can be used to perform UTF7-based attacks
> }
> ```

If you do not want to use `JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping` but also don't want to have `'` escaped, could create a custom [`JsonConverter<string>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=net-6.0) that manually pieces together the required encoded JSON string, then writes it out using [`Utf8JsonWriter.WriteRawValue()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writerawvalue?view=net-6.0) (which was first introduced in .NET 6):

```
public class StringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    readonly static Lazy<JavaScriptEncoder> Encoder = new (() => 
        {
            var encoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings();
            encoderSettings.AllowRange(UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin);
            encoderSettings.AllowCharacters('\u0027');

            return JavaScriptEncoder.Create(encoderSettings);
        });

    public override string? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => reader.GetString();

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var encoder = Encoder.Value;
        
        using var textWriter = new StringWriter();

        textWriter.Write("\"");
        foreach (var (startIndex, characterCount, final) in value.SplitIndices('\''))
        {
            encoder.Encode(textWriter, value, startIndex, characterCount);
            if (!final)
                textWriter.Write('\'');
        }
        textWriter.Write("\"");
        
        writer.WriteRawValue(textWriter.ToString(), true);
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<(int startIndex, int characterCount, bool final)> SplitIndices(this string value, char separator)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        int index = 0;
        int nextIndex;
        while ((nextIndex = value.IndexOf(separator, index)) >= 0)
        {
            yield return (index, nextIndex - index, false);
            index = nextIndex + 1;
        }
        yield return (index, value.Length - index, true);
    }
}
```

Then serialize as follows:

```
var model = new { text = "abc 'zorro' 123" };

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new StringConverter() },
};
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, options);
```

Which results in `{"text":"abc 'zorro' 123"}` as required. Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kr2kl4).

You could also try to create your own [`JavaScriptEncoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder?view=net-6.0) subclass that ignores global block lists, though that would likely be more involved that creating the custom converter.